# Error when trying to view a previous version of an entry

Tags: error-message, entry-versions

I got this weird error message when trying to view a previous revision...

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_8mvcY59Y5sz9qAyfufetQi5LWATEmqwdMnVR' in 'field list'

[image: Error: Unknown column]

I didn't really do anything too unusual... I simply tried to view a previous version of the entry.

[image: View revisions]

Disclaimer... This is a very large website, and it's evolved *a lot* over the past year or so. I'm guessing this might have something to do with a field that has changed, but I really have no clue.

**What does this mean? How did I get here? And how do I fix it?**

Comment: I would bet the same Lindsey :(

Comment: This one is going to be super-tough to debug without the actual database.  If you want to send it over to support@craftcms.com, we can take a stab at it and update here accordingly.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how this is resolved. Looks like a super random field too...